# What is the data type of Facebook's app-scoped id?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm in the process of transitioning a Facebook Graph API integration from v1.0 to v2.0.  One point of concern that I have is the original developer on this project was storing facebook user_ids in a MySQL table as a BIGINT.  It appears that the app-scoped user_ids are strings.  Are these numeric strings?  Or is there a possibility that they would be alphanumeric thus potentially causing me a headache with this MySQL table?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the `id` field of the User object is `string`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user#fields

Personally, I never saw any non-numeric app-scoped Ids, but that's what the docs say.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I haven't seen a non-numeric id as well.  Was hoping someone could give me a definitive answer.  I suppose I should just bite the bullet and convert that MySQL column to a VARCHAR.

Comment: The document now specify it as "numeric string", which mean, at least in specific versions, you can treat it as numeric.